# ActiveWorkbook.Styles VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When I select an item from the drop down list my code goes to palette sheet (Contains of 100 Items cell “B5” has match formula and named as “Ref_rowOffset”.  Next to items, I have 4 colours A, B, C, D) find the item and applies the colours for the tables. The table has been referenced as A, B, C, D. But as I have some sheets that contains from many pivot tables and slicers so the code won’t work for it. So the plan is to name ActiveWorkbook.Styles as let’s say as ("A") and use as reference.  Any ideas would be fantastic?

```
Public Function get_color(str_type As String) As String
    Dim iColOffset As Integer
    Dim strRange As Range
    Select Case str_type
        Case Is = "A"
            iColOffset = 1
        Case Is = "B"
            iColOffset = 2
        Case Is = "C"
            iColOffset = 3
        Case Is = "D"
            iColOffset = 4
        Case Else
    End Select
    iRowOffset = Sheets("Palette").Range("Ref_rowOffset").Value
    Set strRange = Sheets("Palette").Range("B5")
    get_color = strRange.Offset(iRowOffset, iColOffset).Interior.Color
End Function

Public Sub ABSD()
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A").Interior.Color = get_color("A")
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B").Interior.Color = get_color("B")
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C").Interior.Color = get_color("C")
    Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D").Interior.Color = get_color("D")
End Sub
```

Comment: You could remove your `Select Case` statement to `iColOffset = Asc(str_type) - 64`, though I know that's not really your issue.